# How to interpret the result of `np.where`?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm a student new to Numpy and do not have a solid foundation in it. I'm currently trying to identify the largest integer in each row of an array, the row and column of where the integer is in the array and print it out.

However, when attempting to print out the row and column for the largest integer element, I realise that the output keeps printing out the location of the element with " (array..) ". Is there anyway that I can remove the `(array...)` from my output?

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1,1000,(3,4))

#MAX A(s)
maxa = a.max(axis = 1)
arra1 = maxa[np.asarray(0)]
arra2 = maxa[np.asarray(1)]
arra3 = maxa[np.asarray(2)]

#LOCATION OF MAX A(s)
arra1loc = np.where(a == arra1)

print('*** Contents of array a ***')
print(a)
print()

print('Max a = {}'.format(arra1))
print('Row and Column of {} is {}'.format(arra1,arra1loc))
```

My current output:

```
*** Contents of array a ***
[[459 472 918  50]
 [562 556 145 843]
 [638 797 872  61]]

Max a = 918
Row and Column of 918 is (array([0]), array([2]))
```

What i want it to be:

```
*** Contents of array a ***
[[459 472 918  50]
 [562 556 145 843]
 [638 797 872  61]]

Max a = 918
Row and Column of 918 is ([0], [2])
```

Comment: `print('Row and Column of {} is {}'.format(arra1,(arra1loc [0][0], arra1loc [1][0])))`

Comment: Yep i tried.It works well.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `array1loc` is actually a `tuple` of `ndarray` as we can see here `(array([0]), array([2]))` and you can confirm with

```
print(type(arra1loc))    # <class 'tuple'>
print(type(arra1loc[0])) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So you need to apply [`tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) to each `ndarray` of your `tuple`

```
# from numpy import ndarray
arra1loc = tuple(map(ndarray.tolist, arra1loc))
print('Row and Column of {} is {}'.format(arra1, arra1loc))
```